# hide google + button if it is already recommended

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

How can I hide the Google+ button from a visitor if he has already recommended the page. I don't want to hide it only after click, but also to leave the button hidden the next time the user visit the page.

Comment: Unless the API offers some direct option for this, I'd be surprised if it were possible.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575274/is-there-a-easy-way-to-tell-if-a-user-has-google-1-a-url

Comment: Thank tou for your answers. @Mindbreaker i will look into this link and see if a can make it work and update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be careful hiding the button like this, it could cause a bad experience for the user to not be able to remove their +1 if they wanted to. If you're hiding it for aesthetic reasons, that is understandable - for example, if you wanted to show a message and then render a different button that follows [Google+ branding](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) and the [Google+ Buttons policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy).

If you wanted to do it, you could use the callback to put a cookie on the user's machine. The [following demo](http://wheresgus.com/plushide.html) shows a full implementation:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <title>Demo: Hiding +1 after first click</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pluscontainer"></div>
    <h1>Demo: Plus button here</h1>
    <p>
      <span id="plusButton" style="display:none">
        <g:plusone size="tall" callback='cookieAdd'></g:plusone>
      </span>
      <span id="plusMessage" style="display:none;" >
        You have already +1'd this page, click <button onClick='cookieDrop();'>here</button>
        to reshow the button
      </span>
    </p>
  </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    if (document.cookie != undefined && document.cookie.indexOf('enrolled=1') > -1){
      // User +1'd
      $('#plusButton').hide();
      $('#plusMessage').show();
    }else{
      // User hasn't +1'd
      $('#plusButton').show();
      $('#plusMessage').hide();
    }
  })();

  // Remove the cookie (show +1 button)
  function cookieDrop(){
    document.cookie = 'enrolled=0';
    $('#plusMessage').hide();
    $('#plusButton').show();
  }

  // Add the cookie (hide +1 button)
  function cookieAdd(state){
    if (state.state == 'on'){
      document.cookie = 'enrolled=1;expires=0';
      $('#plusMessage').show();
      $('#plusButton').hide();
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solution from Mindbreaker is not working you could add a trigger and save the IP address from the user who +1ed. When the visitor returns, you could simply remove the +1-button with CSS `display:none`.